# How to reduce the size of my Android apps?

Tags: java, android, size

I use ADT Bundle in MAC to program Android apps. I have noticed that the simplest app (Example: an app that only has a button, no images or another resource just a button) is too heavy more than 1 MB. How can I reduce the size of my apps?

Comment: 1 MB is a pretty acceptable app size, trust me.

Comment: http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/01/31/tips-for-reducing-apk-file-size/ seems to contain some info about that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what the comments indicate, I agree that 1MB is very acceptable.

However, further along in development, you may want to use tools like ImageOptim (Mac) to reduce image sizes, or ProGuard to cut out unused methods from libraries you might be using.

Other techniques may include moving heavy content assets to a remote server and download them later on app first launch (rather than part of the install bundle).

Answer (score 0):

APK is not just a format is a compression format, meaning that the apk is already compressed, you need not do another compression type. So I recommend not find another way, there are games that weigh up to 200 MB and it is normal to be a game. A normal app can use 1-5 mb. I think a 1mb is acceptable.